# How do I implement a sparse voxel octree?

Tags: voxels, octree

I've been working on a voxel engine and I want to implement sparse voxel storage. As I understand it, it works a bit differently from a regular octree and has some neat performance increasing "tricks". But I could not find a good explanation with readable source or even pseudocode about how to build them.

I saw lots of references to [this page](https://research.nvidia.com/publication/efficient-sparse-voxel-octrees) but their primary target is GPU, and there is no real source walkthrough there, just the basic idea.

Comment: In case someone else also doesn't know what a *sparse voxel octree* even is, [here's a question about *that*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985893/what-are-sparse-voxel-octrees).

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're stuck on? This question is very broad as it is—it's about a thorough implementation walkthrough of a pretty complex datastructure.

Comment: @Anko No, I'm not stuck anywhere. I have a basic implementation but it's just not that fast. My primary use of them is voxel storage and world generation so I need them to perform better.

Comment: Just confirming; is your question about performance related to building the octree initially, adding elements, or querying a region?